# TikZ tree sibling distance

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I have been struggling a bit with TikZ and how to build trees. What I need now is some advice on how to improve the node placement. Right now I have these 2 trees:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shadows,arrows,trees,shapes,fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[font=\small, edge from parent fork down, 
every node/.style={top color=white, bottom color=blue!25, 
rectangle,rounded corners, minimum size=6mm, draw=blue!75,
very thick, drop shadow, align=center},
edge from parent/.style={draw=blue!50,thick},
level 1/.style={sibling distance=6cm},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=2.5cm}, 
level 3/.style={sibling distance=2.5cm}, 
level distance=2cm,
]

\node {Paletizar} % root
    child { node {Iniciar} 
        child { node {Detectar Pacote}}
        child { node {Movimentar}}
        }
    child { node {Empacotar}
        child { [sibling distance=15mm] node {Posicionar}
            child { node {Pegar/Largar}}
            child { node {Organizar}}
            child { node {Movimentar}}
            }
        child { node {Agrupar}}
        child { node {Padronizar}}
        }
    child { node {Finalizar} 
        child { node {Detectar estado\\da palete}}
        child { node {Transmitir}}
};
\end{tikzpicture}


\vspace{2cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[font=\small, edge from parent fork down, 
    every node/.style={top color=white, bottom color=blue!25, 
    rectangle,rounded corners, minimum size=6mm, draw=blue!75,
    very thick, drop shadow, align=center},
    edge from parent/.style={draw=blue!50,thick},
    level 1/.style={sibling distance=6cm},
    level 2/.style={sibling distance=3cm}, 
    level 3/.style={sibling distance=2cm}, 
    level distance=2cm,
    ]

    \node {Paletizador} % root
        child { node {Inicialização\\de sistema} 
            child { node {Sensor X}}
            child { node {Acção Y}}
            }
        child { node {Sacos}
            child { node {Linha/Coluna}
                child { node {Garra}}
            child { node {Rodar Garra}}
            child { node {Acção Y2}}
            }
        child { node {Euro Pallet}}
        child { node {Disposição $xyz$}
            child { node {$x=?$}}
            child { node {$y=?$}}
            child { node {$z=?$}}
            }
        }
    child { node {Sistema de despacho} 
        child { node {Sensor de peso\\/contador}}
        child { node {Tapete rolante\\de saída}}
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

So basically what I want is a way to edit the code I have so that everything is perceptible which basically means that I need specific sibling distances to each child. I have tried to add a sibling distance in the child nodes but maybe it was in the wrong place or something else because it didn't change anything. I also tried to use below and all its derivations but the results were even worse because of the size of the boxes.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) It's not necessary to sign your questions (as there is already a box with your username below it) or to begin them with a greeting.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using `tikz-qtree` helps a bit with automatic spacing of siblings.  It also provides a simpler input method.  Here's your second tree done in that way:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,trees}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{font=\small,
edge from parent fork down,
level distance=1.75cm,
every node/.style=
    {top color=white,
    bottom color=blue!25,
    rectangle,rounded corners,
    minimum height=8mm,
    draw=blue!75,
    very thick,
    drop shadow,
    align=center,
    text depth = 0pt
    },
edge from parent/.style=
    {draw=blue!50,
    thick
    }}

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree [.Paletizador
        [.{Inicialização\\de sistema}
            [.{Sensor X} ]
            [.{Acção Y} ] ] 
        [.Sacos
            [.{Linha/Coluna} 
                [.{Garra} ]
                [.{Rodar Garra} ]
                [.{Acção Y2} ] ]
            [.{Euro Pallet} ]
            [.{Disposição $xyz$}
                [.{$x=?$} ]
                [.{$y=?$} ]
                [.{$z=?$} ] ] ] 
        [.{Sistema de despacho}
            [.{Sensor de peso\\/contador} ]
            [.{Tapete rolante\\de saída} ] ]
]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: tkiz-qtree helps a lot (I was actually learning how to use it now). However it does create a couple of blank spaces. Is there a way to compact it? Also I seem to loose some horizontal alignment, is there a way to fix that? Other than that it's perfect

Comment: Do you mean the space around the "Linha/Coluna" node? That's determined by the width of its daughter nodes; I don't think there's an easy way to adjust that. As for the alignment of the "y=?" node, I have no idea why that is not aligned properly.

Comment: Ok, I'll leave it at that. Maybe when I have more time I'll try again. Thanks to everyone

Comment: Thanks to @Jake, there's a solution to the horizontal alignment problem: I've added `text depth=0pt` to the node style parameters.

Answer (score 13):

A more compact tree can be specified very concisely using the newer and powerful `forest`. For example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  my node style/.style={
    font=\small,
    top color=white,
    bottom color=blue!25,
    rectangle,
    rounded corners,
    minimum size=6mm,
    draw=blue!75,
    very thick,
    drop shadow,
    align=center,
  }
}
\forestset{
  my tree style/.style={
    for tree={
      my node style,
      parent anchor=south,
      child anchor=north,
      edge={draw=blue!50, thick},
      edge path={% |-| style branches from parent to child
        \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-5pt) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
      },
      if n children=3{% if a node has 3 children
        for children={% align the middle child with its parent
          if n=2{calign with current}{}
        }
      }{},
    }
  }
}
\centering

\begin{forest}
  my tree style
  [Paletizar
    [Iniciar
        [Detectar Pacote]
        [Movimentar]
        ]
    [Empacotar
        [Posicionar
            [Pegar/Largar]
            [Organizar]
            [Movimentar]
        ]
        [Agrupar]
        [Padronizar]
    ]
    [Finalizar
        [Detectar estado\\da palete]
        [Transmitir]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}

\vspace{2cm}

\begin{forest}
  my tree style
  [Paletizador
        [Inicialização\\de sistema
            [Sensor X]
            [Acção Y]
            ]
      [Sacos
          [Linha/Coluna
            [Garra]
            [Rodar Garra]
            [Acção Y2]
          ]
        [Euro Pallet]
        [{Disposição $xyz$}
          [{$x=?$}]
          [{$y=?$}]
          [{$z=?$}]
        ]
      ]
    [Sistema de despacho
      [{Sensor de peso\\/contador}]
      [Tapete rolante\\de saída]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: compact trees]

If you need to keep the trees in portrait and can adjust the relative alignments a little, you can do this quite easily. In this version, I also make use of the vertical space available in portrait orientation to increase the distance between levels a little. The first tree uses tier alignment using `tier=<tier name>` and the second uses empty nodes to adjust the alignment, setting all empty nodes to `shape=coordinate` by modifying the style definition.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  my node style/.style={
    font=\small,
    top color=white,
    bottom color=blue!25,
    rectangle,
    rounded corners,
    minimum size=6mm,
    draw=blue!75,
    very thick,
    drop shadow,
    align=center,
  }
}
\forestset{
  my tree style/.style={
    for tree={
      parent anchor=south,
      child anchor=north,
      l sep+=5pt,
      my node style,
      edge={draw=blue!50, thick},
      edge path={
        \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-7.5pt) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
      },
      if n children=3{
        for children={
          if n=2{calign with current}{}
        }
      }{},
      delay={if content={}{shape=coordinate}{}}
    }
  }
}
\centering

\begin{forest}
  my tree style
  [Paletizar
    [Iniciar
        [Detectar Pacote]
        [Movimentar]
        ]
    [Empacotar
        [Posicionar
            [Pegar/Largar]
            [Organizar]
            [Movimentar]
        ]
        [Agrupar]
        [Padronizar, tier=A]
    ]
    [Finalizar, tier=A
        [Detectar estado\\da palete]
        [Transmitir]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}

\vspace{2cm}

\begin{forest}
  my tree style
  [Paletizador
        [Inicialização\\de sistema
            [Sensor X]
            [Acção Y]
            ]
      [Sacos
        [
          [
            [Linha/Coluna
              [Garra]
              [Rodar Garra]
              [Acção Y2]
            ]
            [Euro Pallet]
            [{Disposição $xyz$}
              [{$x=?$}]
              [{$y=?$}]
              [{$z=?$}]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    [Sistema de despacho
      [Sensor de peso\\/contador]
      [Tapete rolante\\de saída]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: portrait trees]

Answer (score 5):

I am not completely sure that this is actually what you want. You can easily change your code a bit to get everything to fit though. Adding the `fullpage` package to ensure it fits on the page properly and slightly adjusting the sibling distances for the different levels is enough.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shadows,arrows,trees,shapes,fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[font=\small, edge from parent fork down, 
every node/.style={top color=white, bottom color=blue!25, 
rectangle,rounded corners, minimum size=6mm, draw=blue!75,
very thick, drop shadow, align=center},
edge from parent/.style={draw=blue!50,thick},
level 1/.style={sibling distance=6cm},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=2.5cm}, 
level 3/.style={sibling distance=2.5cm}, 
level distance=2cm,
]
\node {Paletizar} % root
    child { node {Iniciar} 
        child { node {Detectar Pacote}}
        child { node {Movimentar}}
        }
    child { node {Empacotar}
        child { [sibling distance=15mm] node {Posicionar}
            child { node {Pegar/Largar}}
            child { node {Organizar}}
            child { node {Movimentar}}
            }
        child { node {Agrupar}}
        child { node {Padronizar}}
        }
    child { node {Finalizar} 
        child { node {Detectar estado\\da palete}}
        child { node {Transmitir}}
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{2cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[font=\small, edge from parent fork down, 
    every node/.style={top color=white, bottom color=blue!25, 
    rectangle,rounded corners, minimum size=6mm, draw=blue!75,
    very thick, drop shadow, align=center},
    edge from parent/.style={draw=blue!50,thick},
    level 1/.style={sibling distance=6cm},
    level 2/.style={sibling distance=2.5cm}, 
    level 3/.style={sibling distance=1.75cm}, 
    level distance=2cm,
    ]
    \node {Paletizador} % root
        child { node {Inicialização\\de sistema} 
            child { node {Sensor X}}
            child { node {Acção Y}}
            }
        child { node {Sacos}
            child { node {Linha/Coluna}
                child { node {Garra}}
            child { node {Rodar Garra}}
            child { node {Acção Y2}}
            }
        child { node {Euro Pallet}}
        child { node {Disposição $xyz$}
            child { node {$x=?$}}
            child { node {$y=?$}}
            child { node {$z=?$}}
            }
        }
    child { node {Sistema de despacho} 
        child { node {Sensor de peso\\/contador}}
        child { node {Tapete rolante\\de saída}}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: TikZ Tree diagram]

You might want to look into some other package, like [`qtree`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/qtree) to draw your trees, if the nodes don't need to look as fancy and you want some automatic placement. If you do want the *fancyness* of TikZ, there is also [`tikz-qtree`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-qtree).

Comment: Since `qtree` is designed solely for linguistic trees, it has few options for changing the branch shape, so for these kinds of trees, `tikz-qtree` is a better choice.