# Set distance for every sibling individually in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I have the following code in LaTeX:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={draw, circle}, -, 
        level/.style = {level distance = 1.5cm, sibling distance = 1cm},
        level 1/.style={sibling distance=3cm}]
        \node [minimum size=0.75cm]{$\rightarrow$\strut}
        child { node[rectangle, minimum size=0.75cm] {a\strut} }
        child { node [minimum size=0.75cm] {$\land$} 
            child { node [rectangle, minimum size=0.75cm] {b\strut}}
            child { node [rectangle, minimum size=0.75cm] {c\strut}}
            child { node [rectangle, minimum size=0.75cm] {d\strut}}
            child { node [rectangle, minimum size=0.75cm] {e\strut}}
        }
        child { node[rectangle, minimum size=0.75cm] {g\strut} }
        child { node [minimum size=0.75cm] {$\times$} 
            child { node [rectangle, minimum size=0.75cm] {h\strut}}
            child { node [rectangle, minimum size=0.75cm] {\tau \strut}}
        }
        child { node [minimum size=0.75cm] {$\land$} 
            child { node [rectangle, minimum size=0.75cm] {i\strut}}
            child { node [rectangle, minimum size=0.75cm] {j\strut}}
            child { node [rectangle, minimum size=0.75cm] {k\strut}}
            child { node [rectangle, minimum size=0.75cm] {l\strut}}
            child { node [minimum size=0.75cm] {$\times$} 
                child { node [rectangle, minimum size=0.75cm] {m\strut}}
                child { node [rectangle, minimum size=0.75cm] {\tau \strut}}
            }
        }
        child { node[rectangle, minimum size=0.75cm] {n\strut} };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

It produces this output:

[image]

How can i set the distance between *g*, the *logical and*, the *multiplication symbol* and the *right and* so that the *tau* and *i* node do not overlap?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please extend your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: You can set `[sibling distance=15mm]` within a child to only affect that child. But there are also more automatic ways using `qtree` or `forest`, see [TikZ tree sibling distance](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35526/123129).

Comment: If you cross-post the same question on multiple different sites, you should include links to all other versions of the question in every version of your question.

Comment: x-post https://stackoverflow.com/q/75676656/2777074

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider using the `forest` package, which will prevent overlapping nodes by default.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={draw, minimum size=.75cm, l sep=7mm, if n children=0{text depth=0, text height=1.5ex}{circle}},
s sep=1cm
[$\rightarrow$, minimum size=1cm
    [a]
    [$\land$
        [b][c][d][e]
    ]
    [g]
    [$\times$
        [h][$\tau$]
    ]
    [$\land$
        [i][j][k][l][$\times$[m][$\tau$]]
    ]
    [n]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```