# Optimize tikz in combination with other packages // graphical visualization of chess opening repertoire

Tags: chess, tikz-pgf

Is there a possibility to write the code in an easier way?:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=42in,paperheight=40in,margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{skak} %package to display chessboards with notation
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagenumbering{gobble} % avoid page numbering

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
        level 1/.style={sibling distance=32cm,}, %x-spacing
        level 2/.style={sibling distance=0cm,},
        level 3/.style={sibling distance=17cm,},
        level 4/.style={sibling distance=0cm,},
        level 5/.style={sibling distance=7cm,},
        level distance=7cm, %y-spacing
        line width=2,]
%
\node {\newgame \mainline{1.f4} \storegame{move1000} \showboard}
    child {  node {\restoregame{move1000} \mainline{1...Nf6} \showboard}
        child {  node { \mainline{2.g3} \storegame{move1100} \showboard}
            child {  node {\restoregame{move1100} \mainline{2...d5}  \showboard}
                child {  node { \mainline{3. Bg2} \storegame{move1110} \showboard}
                    child {  node {\restoregame{move1110} \mainline{3...e6}  \showboard}
                        child {  node { \mainline{4. a4}  \showboard}
                            child {  node { \mainline{4...c6}  \showboard}
                                child {  node [rectangle, minimum size=7.5cm] {eval: -0.1}}
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    child {  node {\restoregame{move1110} \mainline{3...e6}  \showboard}
                        child {  node {\mainline{4. a4}  \showboard}
                            child {  node {\mainline{4...c6}  \showboard}
                                child {  node [rectangle, minimum size=7.5cm] {eval: -0.2}}
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    child {  node {\restoregame{move1110} \mainline{3...c5}  \showboard}
                        child {  node [rectangle, minimum size=7.5cm] {-0.3}}
                    }
                }
            }
            child {  node {\restoregame{move1100} \mainline{2...g6}  \showboard}
                child {  node [rectangle, minimum size=7.5cm] {eval: -0.2}}
            }
            child {  node {\restoregame{move1100} \mainline{2...c5}  \showboard}
                child {  node { \mainline{3. Nf3}  \showboard}
                    child {  node [rectangle, minimum size=7.5cm] {eval: -0.2}}
                }
            }
        }
    }
%
    child {  node [operator, xshift=-0cm] {\restoregame{move1000} \mainline{1...e5} \showboard} 
        child {  node {\mainline{2. fxe5} \showboard} 
            child {  node {\mainline{2...d6} \showboard} 
                child {  node {\mainline{3. exd6} \showboard} 
                    child {  node {\mainline{3...Bxd6} \showboard} 
                        child {  node {\mainline{4. Nf3} \showboard} 
                            child {  node {\mainline{4...Nf6} \showboard} 
                                    child {  node [rectangle, minimum size=7.5cm] {eval: +0.7}}                            
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
%
    child {  node [operator, xshift=-20cm] {\restoregame{move1000} \mainline{1...f5} \showboard} 
        child {  node {\mainline{2. Nf3} \showboard} 
            child {  node {\mainline{2...Nf6} \showboard} 
                child {  node {\mainline{3. c4} \showboard} 
                    child {  node {\mainline{3...c5} \showboard} 
                        child {  node {\mainline{4. b3} \showboard} 
                            child {  node {\mainline{4...g6} \showboard} 
                                child {  node {\mainline{5. g3} \showboard} 
                                    child {  node {\mainline{5...Nc6} \showboard} 
                                        child {  node {\mainline{6. Bg2} \showboard} 
                                            child {  node {\mainline{6... Bg7} \showboard}  
                                                child {  node {\mainline{7. Bb2} \showboard} 
                                                    child {  node [rectangle, minimum size=7.5cm] {eval: +0.3}}
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }    
%
    child {  node [operator, xshift=-40cm] {\restoregame{move1000} \mainline{1...g6} \showboard} 
        child {  node {\mainline{2. Nf3} \showboard} 
            child {  node {\mainline{2...d5} \showboard} 
                child {  node {\mainline{3. e3} \showboard} 
                    child {  node {\mainline{3...Bg7} \showboard} 
                        child {  node {\mainline{4. d4} \showboard} 
                            child {  node {\mainline{4...c5} \showboard} 
                                child {  node {\mainline{5. Bd3} \showboard} 
                                    child {  node [rectangle, minimum size=7.5cm] {eval: -0.4}}
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
%
    child {  node [operator, xshift=-60cm] {\restoregame{move1000} \mainline{1...b6} \showboard} 
        child {  node {\mainline{2. e4} \showboard} 
            child {  node {\mainline{2...Bb7} \showboard} 
                child {  node {\mainline{3. d3} \showboard} 
                    child {  node {\mainline{3...e6} \showboard} 
                        child {  node {\mainline{4. Bd2} \showboard} 
                            child {  node {\mainline{4...Nc6} \showboard} 
                                child {  node {\mainline{5. Nf3} \showboard} 
                                    child {  node [rectangle, minimum size=7.5cm] {eval: -0.1}}
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
%
;
\end{tikzpicture};
%
\end{document}
```

for obtaining a similar result:

[image]

I would appreciate something like forest:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35526/tikz-tree-sibling-distance

(Optionally, I would favor to put the move description on the line before the chess board, something like "\newline" before the chess board)

Comment: I tried the LaTeX code from the shared webpage url, from cfr, with the forest package, just by replacing the string by \mainline{5. Nf3} \showboard but I wasn't able to reproduce so far.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach, which:

- starts with your code
- provides some `refactoring` with focus on shorter lines, i.e. better readability (hopefully)
- sketches a transfer to package `forest`

#### Start

1. What I recognized is that you'll have a huge drawing on a small sheet of paper. Assuming, papersize isn't relevant, I replaced the `article` class by `standalone`, which enlarges the "page" as needed. As a by-product, most packages became obsolete.
2. I couldn't compile with all children and couldn't localize the problem, so I reduced to those, which did compile: this is basically the first child-branch. So from this point onwards it's more a demo and less a 1:1 translation.

#### Refactoring

3. Next, I recognized repeating pattern of node-content AND node-style. The style I defined as `evl` in the beginning of the `tikzpicture`, where `rectangle`, the default shape, is obsolete. The node-content turned out to be very systematic, so I decided to refactor those into 3 TeX-macros `\restg`, `\mainl` and `\mnlne`. Replacing by more useful names would be a next refactoring step, not done here. *(Almost always Tikz will fail when using \newcommands inside a tikzpicture environment, while TeX macros seem to work well, on the expense of all those checking features that come with a \newcommand.)*
4. The resulting code is a bit more compact now per line, though there is a lot of white-space-noise left. Working on those is a matter of taste and preference. So I left it more or less as is.
5. It's so easy to get lost in this tree, and in the forest, too ...

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}% if you're not bound to a papersize
    %\documentclass[landscape]{article}
    %\usepackage[paperwidth=42in,paperheight=40in,margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{skak} %package to display chessboards with notation
    %\usepackage{tikz} % already called with standalone
    %\pagenumbering{gobble} % avoid page numbering % standalone is one big page

% ~~~ refactoring: some shortcuts ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\def\restg#1#2{\restoregame{move#1} \mainline{#2} \showboard}
\def\mainl#1#2{\mainline{#1} \storegame{move#2} \showboard}
\def\mnlne#1{\mainline{#1} \showboard}

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
        level 1/.style={sibling distance=32cm,}, %x-spacing
        level 2/.style={sibling distance=0cm,},
        level 3/.style={sibling distance=17cm,},
        level 4/.style={sibling distance=0cm,},
        level 5/.style={sibling distance=7cm,},
        level distance=7cm, %y-spacing
        line width=2,
        %
        % refactoring:
        evl/.style={minimum size=7.5cm,fill=teal!5}, % eval-style; rectangle = default shape
    ]
%
\node {\newgame \mainline{1.f4} \storegame{move1000} \showboard}
    child {  node { \restg{1000}{1...Nf6} }
        child {  node { \mainl{2.g3}{1100} }
            child {  node {\restg{1100}{2...d5}}
                child {  node { \mainl{3. Bg2}{1110} }
                    child {  node { \restg{1110}{3...e6} }
                        child {  node { \mnlne{4. a4} }
                            child {  node { \mnlne{4...c6} }
                                child {  node [evl] {eval: -0.1}}
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    child {  node {\restg{1110}{3...e6}}
                        child {  node { \mnlne{4. a4} }
                            child {  node { \mnlne{4...c6} }
                                child {  node [evl] {eval: -0.2}}
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    child {  node {\restg{1110}{3...c5}}
                        child {  node [evl] {-0.3} }% <<< intended to miss eval?
                    }
                }
            }
            child {  node {\restg{1100}{2...g6}}
                child {  node [evl] {eval: -0.2} }
            }
            child {  node {\restg{1100}{2...c5}}
                child {  node { \mnlne{3. Nf3} }
                    child {  node [evl] {eval: -0.2} }
                }
            }
        }
    }
;
\end{tikzpicture}%;
%
\end{document}
```

[image: repro1]

#### Forest

Reusing above's final code I started transfer to forest. I amust admit, I quickly got lost in the excact flow of chess moves and game restorations. So here is more a demo, leaving out all the bells and whistles of forest finetuning. (The content now is certainly close to being useless.)

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}% if you're not bound to a papersize
\usepackage{skak} %package to display chessboards with notation
\usepackage{forest}

% ~~~ refactoring: some shortcuts ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\def\restg#1#2{\restoregame{move#1} \mainline{#2} \showboard}
\def\mainl#1#2{\mainline{#1} \storegame{move#2} \showboard}
\def\mnlne#1{\mainline{#1} \showboard}

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
    [\newgame \mainline{1.f4} \storegame{move1000} \showboard
        [\restg{1000}{1...Nf6}
            [\mainl{2.g3}{1100}]    
            [\restg{1000}{1...g6}
                [eval: -0.2]            
            ]   
            [\restg{1000}{1...b6}]  
        ]
    ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: forestdemo]

#### Concluding remarks

1. Many layout relevant aspects can be adjusted in both approaches, like:

- distances and placements
- shape of connectors (straight as here, or rectangular or with rounded corneres etc.)
- frames and colors
- etc.

2. Key is certainly to build branches in a logical, easy to grasp way. A tool could be e.g. to place the main branches first, and `\input` subbranches from dedicated files, which just contain a useful series of `[ ... ]` constructs.
3. If I get it right, package `skak` can hide outputting the moves specified. If so, you could:

- put the move inside a dedicated \node, which you place where you need it (i.e. no longer to the lower left)
- modify said macros a little bit
- a useful `Tikz` command would be `\pic`, together with `args` for passing parameters, where \pic just draws the whole chess board and places the move where needed (regard `\pic` as a drawing macro from `Tikz`)